# Hypothesis testing with multiple variables

Tags: binomial-distribution, ab-test, z-test

I'm trying to understand the process behind testing both A/B site changes for statistically significant increases in conversion rate, and also how then to expand this to testing multiple variables.

My understanding is that this is a binomial distribution (n=visits, p=conversion rate), and using z-scores, significance can be calculated like this: https://vwo.com/blog/ab-testing-significance-calculator-spreadsheet-in-excel/.

What do I do if I have multiple variables though? I have previously compared each variation to the average performance of all other variations, but this feels open to misrepresentation of actual significance.

Would it be better to set one variation as the control and compare each new variation to the control only? Or should they be all be tested individually against each other?

**Further Clarification:**

I have accrued data for pages v1, v2, v3 and v4, and would like to determine based on this data (visits/conversions) which pages are significantly better or worse, in comparison to one another.

I understand the comparison of say, v1 versus v2, but with 4 variables, should I compare v1 to v2+v3+v4? My concern with this approach is that by averaging what could be two extremes, they balance out and fail to yield a significant result (despite significant results when compared individually).

Comment: for clarification: you want ideas for testing a change on a single feature A against multiple alternatives B1,B2,Bn or testing changes of multiple features A1, A2, .. each against B1, B2, .. or both of them combined?

Comment: I have accrued data for pages v1, v2, v3 and v4, and would like to determine based on this data (visits/conversions) which pages are significantly better or worse, in comparison to one another. I understand the comparison of say, v1 versus v2, but with 4 variables, should I compare v1 to v2+v3+v4? Or do they need to be compared as v1 to v2, v1 to v3, v1 to v4? (not sure if this is clearer)